# How to keep table structure up-to-date

Tags: php, mysql, schema

Does anyone have an idea for a scipt that can check an array/XML of table definitions with the current database tables and make appropriate alter/create queries to synch them? I'm currently using php5 and mysql 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that MySQL Workbench is able to create alter/diff SQL scripts

Answer (score 0):

pick some database migration framework or write your own. and read this https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/